# How to get Harris corners that are present in watershed segmented Bitwise image(road part)?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, image-segmentation

- This is Harris corner image of test image:

  [image]
- This is Bitwise watershed segmented image:

  [image]

I want to get that Harris corners which will be in segmented part of image(road part).

Comment: Can you please add a little bit more information about what you are trying to achieve as, at the moment, it is not exactly clear what you are asking. In the meantime, if you do have the "mask" of the road then all you have to do is query for those harris corners whose pixel locations appear to be within the mask.

Comment: My aim is to detect white stripes on road .So I have done Harris Corner Detection and on other hand for pre processing I have done bilateral filter then watershed image segmentation then i have done bitwise_and of image to get that rod part.Now main thing to detect white stripes

Answer (score 1):

You have a mask of the road were pixels of the road have value 1 and non road pixels as value 0.
Also you have a list of Harris corners were each corner as a coordinate Xi,Yi

1. For each Xi,Yi i corners
2. If mask[Xi,Yi] == 1
3. keep corner